# JumpCount resets immediately after jumping 2D platformer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to all of this so sorry for rookie mistakes. I'm making a 2D platformer
I am checking for ground via RayCast and right after the player jumps, the jumpCounter resets to 0, so I get a bonus jump. I tried adding a 0.2s timer before it can reset but that caused trouble when jumping multiple times in a row (bunny hopping). Any help?

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GroundCheck();
        if (state != State.hurt)
        {
            Movement();
            DoubleJump();
            StateMachine();
        }

        HurtCheck();
        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }
    private void Movement()
    {
        //Input.GetAxis returns a value between -1 up to 1
        //Edit> Project Settings> Input> Axis> Horizontal
        float hDirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        //holding down "D" makes the value positive and vice versa
        if (hDirection < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1, 1);
        }
        else if (hDirection > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        }
        else
        {

        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpforce);
        state = State.jumping;
        jumpCount += 1;
    }
    private void GroundCheck()
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.down * hitDistance, Color.green);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, hitDistance, ground);
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            jumpCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
    private void DoubleJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == false && jumpCount < 2)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpforce);
            jumpCount += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's `HurtCheck` doing?

Comment: I have a feeling the value of `Vector2.down * hitDistance` is too large, and the ray strikes the platform the first frame after the jump, thus resetting it to 0. Try using `OnCollisionEnter` in a script on the floor to do the resetting.

Comment: This solved my issue. Raycast was too large, but I needed it for having running animation on slopes so I created a different one and moved `IsGrounded` to `OnCollisionEnter2D`. Thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Have you made sure your player's layer isn't `ground` layer or set `ground` layermask properly or maybe the `hitDistance` for the `raycast` is too high it should be very low like `0.1` or less or does `jumpCount` start from `0` or `1` try and alternate that or maybe have it start from two to lose the extra bonus jump...These would be where I would look, Good luck!

Comment: hitDistance for raycast is pretty high just because I want it to be able to reach the ground when the player is standing on a slope.

Comment: Does it work as expected when you lower hitDistance? and for slope detection it's better to use BoxCast instead of raycast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3iEl5AwUF8 this is a very good tutorial on how to do it. Good luck and please green tick me if I solved your problem!